# Two y-axes Chart [Google Engine]

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have 2 lists (features) and I wanted to join in a graph, where the X axis would be the months and the Y axis would be the monthly data of TRMM and the other one of MODIS.

```
var multiYrGraph2 = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: multyrMonthTS,
  xProperty:'month',
  yProperties: 'value'})          
      .setChartType("ColumnChart").setChartType('LineChart')
      .setOptions({vAxis: {title: 'LST [deg. C]'},
                    hAxis: {title: 'Month'}});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea2d1f05fd2e642982057fa32d3c15bf

---

Actually I am trying to put the TRMM data on a Y-axis (left) and the MODIS data also on a Y-axis (right), and the X-axis would be the months.

Example:

[image: https://images.climate-data.org/location/6972/climate-graph.png]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  We are a little different from other sites - we're a focused Question and Answer site rather than a discussion forum.  Please [edit] your post to ask an actual question - tell us about your problem, what you've tried (and the result) and what you are expecting.  Give details, and include any code you are working with.

Comment: A reproducible example: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/812184192381d3665f8c37c3dfa1a61d)